# How to anchor a transistor along a direction with circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits, alignment, anchor

I'm drawing a simple nmos differential pair with a bias transistor and I want to connect the drain of the bias transistor to the midpoint of the sources of the differential pairs.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx,arrowmos]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

   \begin{circuitikz}[american resistors]
   \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
   \draw[color=black,thick]  
  (0,3) node[nmos] (dpair1) {}
  (2,3) node[nmos, xscale=-1] (dpair2) {}
  ($(dpair1.S)!0.5!(dpair2.S)$) node [] (midsource) {}
  (dpair1.S) to[short,-*] (midsource) to[short,-] (dpair2.S)
  ([yshift=-1.5cm]midsource) to[Tnmos, n=nbias] ([yshift=-1cm]midsource)
  ;
   \draw[color=black,thick]   
  (4,3) node[nmos] (dpair1) {}
  (6,3) node[nmos, xscale=-1] (dpair2) {}
  ($(dpair1.S)!0.5!(dpair2.S)$) node [] (midsource) {}
  (dpair1.S) to[short,-*] (midsource) to[short,-] (dpair2.S)
  ([yshift=-0.5cm]midsource) node[nmos, anchor=north] () {}
  ;
   \draw[color=black,thick]  
  (8,3) node[nmos] (dpair1) {}
  (10,3) node[nmos, xscale=-1] (dpair2) {}
  ($(dpair1.S)!0.5!(dpair2.S)$) node [] (midsource) {}
  (dpair1.S) to[short,-*] (midsource) to[short,-] (dpair2.S)
  ([yshift=-1.5cm]midsource) to[Tnmos, n=nbias,mirror] ([yshift=-1cm]midsource)
  ;
   \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

I haven't been able to achieve that, as shown in the code examples.
I want to be able to do that relatively to the position of the differential pair source and not using absolute coordinates. 
When I use the node function with `anchor=north` (example in the middle) it doesn't align the anchor (drain) to the starting point, but to the transistor's centre, leaving it offset by half the transistor's width. In the other cases using the `(node1) to[nmos] (node2)` syntax, I can't get it to flip/mirror correctly just using mirror command and swapping (node1) for (node2) (examples on the right and left). 
I know there are also `xscale=-1` and `yscale=-1` commands, but when I type them, it sends the transistor to the far corner of the sheet and doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

[image: The three different attempts at aligning the bias transistor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, you want this?

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx,arrowmos]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{circuitikz}[american resistors]
  \ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
  \draw[color=black,thick]   
    (0,0) node[nmos] (dpair1) {}
    (2,0) node[nmos, xscale=-1] (dpair2) {}
    ($(dpair1.S)!0.5!(dpair2.S)$) node [] (midsource) {}
    (dpair1.S) to[short,-*] (midsource) to[short,-] (dpair2.S)
    (midsource) node[nmos, anchor=D] {}
  ;
  \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

See [page 42 of the `circuitikz` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf#page=42) (or page 44–49 in `circuitikz` documentation v 0.8.3 from 2017/05.28) for other anchors.

Comment: That's exactly it, thanks a million. I think in the documentation it is not clear that using either D for drain or north have different outcomes, that's why I hadn't thought of it. On page 42 it shows the transistors anchored with north,south,east,west but on the first line it says that the anchors are gate source bulk drain so it misled me to think they were the same. Cheers.